# Show G has a normal subgroup of a given index

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ $s.t.$ the quotient $G/N$ is cyclic and of order $18$. Show $G$ has a normal subgroup $H$ of index $|G:H|=9$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the maps
$$G\rightarrow G/N\cong \mathbb{Z}/18\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$$
The rightmost map is just the natural reduction mod 9. All the maps above are surjective, so the composition is a surjection $G\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$. Its kernel is normal of index 9.

Comment: Nice and succinct answer

Answer (score 1):

Using the correspondence between the subgroups of $G/N$ and the subgroups of $G$ that contain $N$, we see that $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of index $9$ because so does $G/N$, since it is cyclic.  $H$ must be normal because $H/N$ is normal since $G/N$ is abelian.

Actually, the same is true for every divisor of $18$, not just $9$.

Comment: The correspondence is given by Lattice isomorphism theorem?

Comment: This one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_(group_theory).